# Building with GraalVM native image - Unresolved type during parsing: io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.logging.Log4J2Logger

Tags: quarkus, graalvm, temporal-workflow, quarkus-native

I am using Quarkus and trying to build the native image and got this error
My dependecies

```
dependencies {
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}"))
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-kotlin")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-kubernetes")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-arc")
    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
    implementation("io.temporal:temporal-sdk:1.21.0")
}
```

Error

> Caused by:
> org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError:
> com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException:
> Discovered unresolved type during parsing:
> io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.logging.Log4J2Logger. This
> error is reported at image build time because class
> io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.logging.Log4J2LoggerFactory
> is registered for linking at image build time by command line at
> parsing
> io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.logging.Log4J2LoggerFactory.newInstance(Log4J2LoggerFactory.java:33)
> at
> jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2536)
> at
> org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.throwParserError(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:169)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74838532/175554 may help

Comment: @ozkanpakdil Thank you so much it was useful, I did try adding some log libraries, but not all the libs

Answer (score 0):

Adding these dependencies resovled the issue and now I am able to build native images, Tried different combinations, all these are required.

```
implementation("org.jboss.logging:commons-logging-jboss-logging")
implementation("org.jboss.logmanager:log4j-jboss-logmanager")
implementation("org.jboss.slf4j:slf4j-jboss-logmanager")
implementation("org.jboss.logmanager:log4j2-jboss-logmanager")
```

Found this from the below thread

[GraalVM native image not working with logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070173/graalvm-native-image-not-working-with-logs/74838532#74838532)

Thanks @ozkanpakdil